# Prefix Free or Prefixr?

Tags: css, prefix

What's recommended using Prefix Free or Prefixr?

Using **[Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)**

- prefixing your CSS automatically
- they are loaded only when requested
- these prefixes become dependent of a JS file

Using **[NetTuts' Prefixr](http://prefixr.com)**

- generating your converted CSS automatically
- it will add significant
  weight to your CSS

Comment: "*it will add significant weight to your CSS*": that's not really true. It will make your CSS functional.

Comment: But at a cost of your CSS file size. If you convert a file that has a large number of transforms, for example, you'll soon realize the file size difference.

Comment: It'll be negligible once you gzip it.

Answer (score 2):

- Prefix Free suffers from [FOUC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) (Lea Verou is still awesome though).
- Prefixr is nice, and [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) (among others) [integrates](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Extensions) with [it](https://github.com/davidderaedt/prefixr-extension).

Answer (score 1):

I use a css preprocessor like LESS or SASS that has mixins to handle this.  That allows you to decide whether you want to perform the processing on server or client side.  Generally, I think server-side is better for production use.  The extra size of CSS is usually less important than cutting down on heavy client-side translations.  On one recent project, switching from client to server side LESS saved 500ms on page load on my desktop.